# To Dynamic SQL or Not

Tags: oracle, plsql

When doing an update, we want to do a concurrency check on the ORA_ROWSCN (Oracle db BTW). So I was thinking of creating a function, where you pass in the ora_rowscn you have, table name, column name and an ID. The function would check would do a select statement based on the table, column and id you've passed in and if the returned ora_rowscn is different from the one you passed in, return a true or false is it's the same.

I do validity check on the table_name and column_name passed in to make sure they exists first.

```
FUNCTION ConcurrencyCheck (
  pi_orarowscn_in             IN NUMBER,
  pi_table_name               IN VARCHAR2,
  pi_column_name              IN VARCHAR2,
  pi_id                       IN NUMBER


)
  RETURN BOOLEAN IS

r_data_out_of_date BOOLEAN := false;

ln_orarowscn_current NUMBER := 0;

lv_sql VARCHAR2(300) := '';
lv_column VARCHAR(20) := '';
lv_table VARCHAR(20) := '';

BEGIN

SELECT table_name INTO lv_table from ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = pi_table_name;

IF lv_table = '' THEN
  RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
ELSE
  SELECT column_name INTO lv_column from USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = pi_table_name AND COLUMN_NAME = pi_column_name;

  IF lv_column = '' THEN
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;

  ELSE
    lv_sql := 'select ORA_ROWSCN from ' || pi_table_name || ' where ' || pi_column_name || ' = ' || pi_id || '';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql INTO ln_orarowscn_current;

    IF ln_orarowscn_current <> pi_orarowscn_in THEN
      r_data_out_of_date := true;
    END IF;

  END IF;      
END IF;

RETURN r_data_out_of_date;



EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;

  END ConcurrencyCheck;
```

I do not like the dynamic SQL that I have there. I would much rather (not have dynamic SQL but... ) have it like the following:

```
lv_sql := 'select ORA_ROWSCN from :table_name where :column_name = :id';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql INTO ln_orarowscn_current USING pi_table_name, pi_column_name, pi_id;
```

but I keep getting an SQL error saying the table is wrong

The other solution is to create a sub-function for ALL the tables that would return the ORA_ROWSCN for each and a IF ELSE in the main function to call each.

I'm looking for best practice here. Is this a time where dynamic SQL is acceptable? Or should I go the "long" route and create a ton of functions/procedures for each table?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately bind variables can't be used for table name or column name, only for data, you have no choice you have to use dynamic sql

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is was I thought. Do you think it's better to do it with dynamic SQL or having a bunch of procedure that the main function would call instead?

Comment: I would not create procedures because your code will be more difficult to read and understand. But I think there is way for improvements. For example why don't you check the existence of the table_name and column_name at once?

Comment: The function idea is not bad either, maybe returning a cursor or varray?

Comment: Cyrille : yes of course, that should just be one check. Thanks for your input. Ted : The function, as it is, returns a boolean and it works fine. I'm just wondering about security implecations and best practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for the best practices, in these cases it's recommended to use the `sys.dbms_assert` package.

```
FUNCTION ConcurrencyCheck(
    pi_orarowscn_in             IN NUMBER,
    pi_table_name               IN VARCHAR2,
    pi_column_name              IN VARCHAR2,
    pi_id                       IN NUMBER
)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    ln_orarowscn_current NUMBER := 0;
    lv_sql VARCHAR2(300) := '';
BEGIN
    lv_sql := '
        select X.ora_rowscn
        from '||sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name(pi_table_name)||' X
        where X.'||sys.dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(pi_column_name)||' = :pi_id
    ';
    execute immediate lv_sql
        into ln_orarowscn_current
        using in pi_id;

    return ln_orarowscn_current <> pi_orarowscn_in;
END ConcurrencyCheck;
```

**Note:** If I were in your place, I'd give myself the initial hard time of implementing a metadata-driven code generator for the package of one-check-per-one-table functions that would be, as you may have guessed, static PL/SQL code – giving you all those nice compile-time syntax/semantic checks.